# Getting catagory title total number of questions and answers order by number of questions

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have three tables. Which is in at this fiddle,
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cadb2

Which is like this?.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_answers` (
  `id` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `answer` text NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `user_questions` (
  `id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `note_id` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `material_univarcity_list` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `about` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to get a resultant table which has count - Name(Name is from material_univarcity_list) Total number of questions to that particular name. Here id of `material_univarcity_list` table is the `note_id` of `user_questions` and I want total number of answers to that particular catagory here `question_id` is the id of `user_questions`. How can I do this?

My expected result is like

```
no|catagory        |number_of_questions |number_of_answers
 1|DBMS 5th sem ISE|            2       | 3
 2|DBMS 6th sem ISE|            1       | 1
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT @no := @no + 1 AS no
  ,catagory
  ,number_of_questions
  ,number_of_answers
FROM (
SELECT c.title AS catagory        
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT q.id) AS number_of_questions 
    ,COUNT(a.id) AS number_of_answers
FROM material_univarcity_list_content AS c
LEFT JOIN user_questions AS q ON q.note_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN user_answers AS a ON a.question_id = q.id
GROUP BY c.title ) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @no := 0) AS t2
ORDER BY number_of_questions DESC;
```

Since you use MySQL 5.7 which doesn't support window functions like ROW_NUMBER you need to use user variables to emulate it.

Comment: This is giving me a single return But what I want is a full category list with its respective questions and answers

Comment: I have edited the quesion

Comment: @arunwebber just missed GROUP BY when copy+pasted )

Comment: HI, Its works really great Is there any way to get the catagory which has no questions also in it? Right now the table which is generated is only having catagories which are having questions with it.

Comment: @arunwebber use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN

Comment: Its not showing no the very first column on the expected answer

Comment: Also please change it to desc A small typo sorry about that.

Comment: @arunwebber why do you develop for old MySQL version? it would be easier to use MySQL 8.0

Comment: Its an old system